# Why @objc in "UITapGestureRecognizer"?

Tags: uitapgesturerecognizer, swift4.2

I added `UITapGestureRecognizer` to my `UIView`. But I don't understand why I have to use `@objc` to use `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

In particular, the difference between `Selector?` and `#selector` is too confusing.

And I didn't see an explanation using `@objc` in the [official document of the Apple developer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitapgesturerecognizer).

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let viw = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
        viw.center = self.view.center
        viw.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        self.view.addSubview(viw)

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(sender:)))
        viw.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    @objc func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if sender.state == .ended {
            print(1)
        }
    }
}
```

I think this is an old way. If there is an up-to-date way to add `UITapGestureRecognizer` to `UIView`, I would like to know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why @objc ?**

If you are using any class selectors which is basically written in `Objective-C` than you need to add `@objc` before that function so that `UITapGestureRecognizer` class can revert back with proper event.

If you are not adding `@objc` before your gesture handler function compiler will throw error as mention below :

> Argument of '#selector' refers to instance method 'handleTap()' that
>   is not exposed to Objective-C

It clearly says that you haven't exposed your handle for `Objective-C`.

Apple Officially link for **Language Interoperability**

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift#2984801

Also check this link for more info on

[Use runtime Obj C features in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/using_objective-c_runtime_features_in_swift)

Hope you can get your answer form above explanation!

Comment: Thank you for your kind.